# How to stop IOS app from responding to HTML Refresh in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios4, page-refresh

In my app I load a site that uses ad banners and HTML refresh tags.

Every minute (or however long the refresh HTML tag is set) the app goes out to the network to reloads the iframe banner ad on the website (even if it is hidden)

Is there a way to get webView to ignore these?

I tried stoploading and other things in webViewDidFinishLoading, but it still is responding to the HTML refreshes.

Any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there is javascript on the webpage involved, and that is loading the data? You could try patching the javascript code accordingly, right after having loaded the page (there's a method to execute your own javascript in a loaded page, I think, and so you could inject your own js code that modified the loaded page, maybe disable the banner code or remove its entire div segment).

And isn't there another delegate function that gets called when the page follows a link or loads extra pictures etc? Not sure, been a long time I've touched the webView. Maybe you have to filter the banner picture loading there.

In fact, look at UIWebViewDelegate - there's webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
Have you implemented that to see if you can filter the banner loading there?

Comment: it is not java script.  It is the refresh tag in this iframe.  <IFRAME src="http://smartfamilytour.com/cgi-bin/adspro/ads.pl?campaign=1&refresh=35&type=iframe&color=FFFFFF" height="60" width="468" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" frameborder="0" align="center" scrolling="no">
<ILAYER src="http://smartfamilytour.com/cgi-bin/adspro/ads.pl?campaign=1&refresh=15&type=iframe&color=FFFFFF" height="60" width="468" visibility="show" z-index="10"></ILAYER>
</IFRAME>

Comment: oh, if it's a refresh, I am sure you can filter that with the delegate I mentioned above. And if that helps, please do not forget to mark this question as answered.

Comment: I will need a little more guidance as I have never done a filter before.  Are you saying to grab the HTML before it is loaded and strip out the refresh text?  If so, how will I know what comes after the tag?  i.e.  &refresh=35  vs &refresh=9  Thanks

Comment: Here is the line with the refresh. The above seems to have cut it off.  .../ads.pl?campaign=1&refresh=35&type=iframe&color=FFFFFF%22

Comment: No, you need to learn how to use a delegate in ObjC. Basically, once you have your webView, you can implement the functions from UIWebViewDelegate in your own controller class. Then you tell the webView that you want the webView to call these functions of yours. You do that by assigning "webView.delegate = self", i.e. you tell the webView to look if your (self) has these functions and make them call appropriately. In one of those functions, i.e. webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:, you will be asked to allow the loading of a page. there you can say no if it's the reload.

Comment: I tried this and you do not get a reload call from an iframe with a refresh tag, so I am still getting the refresh on pages that are not visible.

Comment: Ian, I am not sure but I fear that's one of the many limitations of webkit on iOS. To work around this, you might have to load the html code, parse it and modify the loaded html code by removing the refresh tag before giving it to the web view for display. How to do that? Well, that's a whole new question, and maybe there's already an answer for that around here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he is saying is that you should add this to your code :

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navType
{
    NSURL *pURL = [request URL];
    NSString *pString = [pURL absoluteString];

    // some test on pString, which is now your basic URL to decide if you want to do the load or not
    if ( some test )
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

or something similar to that....

I had to do something like this recently, as the UIWebView does not stop loading after the view it is on disappears in my navigation heirarchy, caused mysterious crashes sometime later when the refresh occurs, took me a while to hunt it down actually ....